# if statement using created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
<% if product.created_at %>
  <span class="label label-warning">New!</span>
<% end%>
```

Web dev newbie.. Can't figure out how to use if statement in rails view to display the span class when product records is up to 3 days old. Any ideas?

I can query in my console with

```
variable = Product.where(created_at: 3.days.ago..Time.now)
```

and get the the correct records. But cannot understand how to translate this into rails.

The ERB block is going into a _partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<% if product.created_at > 3.days.ago.beginning_of_day %>
  <span class="label label-warning">New!</span>
<% end%>
```

Comment: If that answer resolves your question, please mark it as accepted if you're able. Thank you!